# Building Wireshark on Ubuntu from source

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, wireshark

While trying to build Wireshark on Ubuntu 16.04 from source code, I encounter this error after running `./configure`:

```
 error: /home/yoyo/anaconda3/bin/lrelease -qt=5 -version returned non-zero exit status
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have python installed in your home directory via anaconda.
Probably you set this via the PATH variable in your .bashrc (or the anaconda installer did)

Try editing .bashrc and removing it so you're using ubu system defaults.
Run the failing command manually to see if it would work or if you have another problem.

```
$ /usr/bin/lrelease -qt=5 -version 
lrelease version 5.5.1
```